# Ideas to cluster lanes using color information

Tags: clustering, numpy, point-cloud

My point cloud consists of XYZ values and for each xyz there is corresponding color (RGB) value. I don't have any other information in my data eg:intensity, classification etc., as this point cloud was derived from images not from LiDAR.

My idea was to extract features  (lanes detection) using RGB data. I found so much from the Google but all are using intensity values from the LiDAR, unfortunately I can't.

What I have done:

1. Read pcd
2. Apply grid
3. Perform Ransac(not showed in the code here)

```
def voxelAvgColor(eachvoxel) : 
  colorinfo = sum(clrs[eachvoxel])/(len(clrs[eachv oxel]))
  return colorinfo

pointcloud = lp.read(”data_01_2021.las”)
points = np.vstack((pointcloud.x, pointcloud.y,pointcloud.z)).transpose()
colors = np.vstack((pointcloud.red, pointcloud.green,pointcloud.blue)).transpose()

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud() pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors/65535) 
rgb = np.asarray(pcd.colors)
xyz = np.asarray(pcd.points) 

o3d.visualization.drawgeometries([pcd])

voxelgrid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.createfrompointcloud(pcd, voxelsize = 0.40)
print(”voxelplottingstarted........”)

o3d.visualization.drawgeometries([voxelgrid])
voxels = voxelgrid.getvoxels()
indices = np.stack(list(vx.gridindex for vx in voxels))
clrs = np.stack(list(vx.color for vx in voxels))
GridPcd =o3d.geometry. PointCloud()
GrodPcd.points=o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(indices)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(clrs)
o3d.visualization.drawgeometries([GridPcd])
```

4. Now to detect the lanes, I want to cluster the inlier points.
   Which clustering is best for my next step? I thought of DBscan and I applied but I can't able to extract the lanes. So, I am looking for other algorithm that takes my color information and form clusters (e.g., based on the color data (since lanes are white it should form cluster on lane markings and road are black and it should form another cluster, some thing like this)

I also tried K means but couldn't extract white lanes.